# Google Apps Script Drive Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

This is my first post on SO so I hope I'm doing this correctly.  I have a Google Apps Script that is being used with as a web hook to create an integration between two services: YouCanBook.Me and Taleo.  The script was published as a web app with the "Anyone, even anonymous" access and was working for weeks.  Recently (as of 2/3/14 I believe) it stopped working and now navigating to the public URL results in the following error message:

> Google Drive encountered an error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please report the error.
>
> To learn more about Google Drive, please visit our help center.
>
> We're sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for your help!
>   - The Google Drive Team

Here is the code for the entire script:

```
function doGet(request) {

  try {
    //Get token data from URL parameters
    var candidateID = request.parameter.candID;
    var requisitionID = request.parameter.reqID;
    var interviewType = request.parameter.intType;
    var requestType = request.parameter.request;
  }
  catch(e) {
    Logger.log('Unable to capture required parameters.  Error message: ' + e);
    return;
  }

  //Get authToken by passing in credentials
  var authToken = taleoLogin();

  //Get candidate application ID
  var candidateApplicationID = getCandidateApplicationID(authToken, candidateID, requisitionID);

  //Make PUT request to change candidate's status
  taleoSubmit(authToken, candidateID, requisitionID, candidateApplicationID, interviewType, requestType);

  //Logout
  taleoLogout(authToken);
}



function getCandidateApplicationID(authToken, candidateID, requisitionID) {
  //Build API call
  var loginURL = 'https://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH06/ats/api/v1/object/candidateapplication?candidateId=' + candidateID + '&requisitionId=' + requisitionID;
  var loginOptions = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers' : {
      'cookie' : authToken
    },
    'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  };

  //Make API call
  try {
    var loginResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(loginURL, loginOptions);
    if (loginResponse.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      Logger.log('Logged in!');
    }
    else {
      Logger.log('Error logging in: ' + loginResponse.getContentText());
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not log in: ' + e);
  }

  //Return candidate application ID
  return candidateApplicationID = JSON.parse(loginResponse).response.candtoreqs[0].candidateapplication.id.toFixed(0);
}



//-----------------------------------//
//  Log into Taleo via the REST API  //
//-----------------------------------//

function taleoLogin() {
  //Build API call
  var loginURL = 'https://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH06/ats/api/v1/login?orgCode=[companyCode]&userName=[username]&password=[password]';
  var loginOptions = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType' : 'application/json'
  };

  //Make API call
  try {
    var loginResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(loginURL, loginOptions);
    if (loginResponse.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      Logger.log('Logged in!');
    }
    else {
      Logger.log('Error logging in: ' + loginResponse.getContentText());
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not log in: ' + e);
  }

  //Return full authToken key
  return authToken = 'authToken=' + JSON.parse(loginResponse).response.authToken;
}


//-------------------------------------//
//  Log out of Taleo via the REST API  //
//-------------------------------------//

function taleoLogout(authToken) { 
  //Build API call
  var logoutURL = 'https://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH06/ats/api/v1/logout';
  var logoutOptions = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : {
      'cookie' : authToken
    },
    'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  };

  //Make API call
  try {
    var logoutResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(logoutURL, logoutOptions);
    if (logoutResponse.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      Logger.log('Logged out!');
    }
    else {
      Logger.log('Error logging out: ' + logoutResponse.getContentText()); 
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not log out: ' + e); 
  }
}


//-----------------------------------------//
//  Submit data to Taleo via the REST API  //
//-----------------------------------------//

function taleoSubmit(authToken, candID, reqID, appID, intType, requestType) {

  //If phone interview and initial booking
  if(intType == 'phone' && requestType == 'booking') {
    //Build API call
    try {
      var submitURL = 'https://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH06/ats/api/v1/object/candidateapplication/' + appID;
      var payload = JSON.stringify({ "candidateapplication" : { "candidateId" : candID, "requisitionId" : reqID, "status" : 5033 }});
      var submitOptions = {
        'method' : 'put',
        'headers' : {
          'cookie' : authToken
        },
        'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'payload' : payload
      };
    }
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Error creating API call: ' + e); 
    }
  }
  else if(intType == 'final' && requestType == 'booking') {
    //Build API call
    try {
      var submitURL = 'https://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH06/ats/api/v1/object/candidateapplication/' + appID;
      var payload = JSON.stringify({ "candidateapplication" : { "candidateId" : candID, "requisitionId" : reqID, "status" : 5048 }});
      var submitOptions = {
        'method' : 'put',
        'headers' : {
          'cookie' : authToken
        },
        'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'payload' : payload
      };
    }
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Error creating API call: ' + e); 
    }
  }
  else if(intType == 'phone' && requestType == 'cancel') {
    //Build API call
    try {
      var submitURL = 'https://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH06/ats/api/v1/object/candidateapplication/' + appID;
      var payload = JSON.stringify({ "candidateapplication" : { "candidateId" : candID, "requisitionId" : reqID, "status" : 5032 }});
      var submitOptions = {
        'method' : 'put',
        'headers' : {
          'cookie' : authToken
        },
        'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'payload' : payload
      };
    }
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Error creating API call: ' + e); 
    }
  }
  else if(intType == 'final' && requestType == 'cancel') {
    //Build API call
    try {
      var submitURL = 'https://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH06/ats/api/v1/object/candidateapplication/' + appID;
      var payload = JSON.stringify({ "candidateapplication" : { "candidateId" : candID, "requisitionId" : reqID, "status" : 5047 }});
      var submitOptions = {
        'method' : 'put',
        'headers' : {
          'cookie' : authToken
        },
        'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'payload' : payload
      };
    }
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Error creating API call: ' + e); 
    }
  }

  //Make API call
  try {
    var submitResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(submitURL, submitOptions);
    if (submitResponse.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      Logger.log('Results submitted!');
    }
    else {
      Logger.log('Error submitting results: ' + submitResponse.getContentText());
    }
  } 
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not submit results: ' + e); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello smackjack3, I'm getting these errors when I wrote something impossible, for exemple when I forgot a "+" sign or when interchanging "+" for "=". my best guess will be the return line 'return authToken = 'authToken=''. but you could try to check your code, removing big part of it. When you don't get this error but the code didn't return what was expected (because incomplete) you'll know where to look for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The code runs fine if I execute it within the code editor.  The "error" is when trying to access/execute the script from the public URL.  I just realized that even though I'm receiving the Google Drive error message, as well as an error message from the YouCanBook.Me service, the script is actually still executing. Apparently, I'm just not getting a 200 response from the server even though the script seems to be executing fine.

Comment: It appears the page is returning a 500 response code for some reason.  I tried to edit the OP, but it keeps telling me the code isn't formatted properly and won't let me save even though I'm not touching that.

Comment: I am getting exactly the same problem.  I also see in logs and trace that my script ran just fine.  But the Google Drive error slams me too.

Comment: @LouisKleiman I've found a workaround thanks to someone in the Google+ community.  If you add the following code to your doGet() function, it seems to fix the issue:

var app = UiApp.createApplication();
return app;

Comment: Hmmm.  But my doGet() is returning HTML, not a UiApp.  I'll keep researching.  Thanks.

Comment: OK.  The error was actually mine.  I found a syntax error in some javascript embedded in the page I was returning.  The error message coming from Drive was very misleading.